# Is it possible to generate C++ template functions that are not inline these days?

Tags: c++, templates, module, inline

It used to be that templated functions were not always inlined. There were tremendous problems in having template functions defined in a .cpp file, since it was unaware of what a different module had passed in as the template argument. So templates were almost always pure header file, everything included.

However, code can be very large, so if I wanted to create a template class, for example Matrix and have the methods actually generated as functions, is there any way to do it?

This used to work:

```
template<typename Precision>
Matrix<Precision> operator *(const Matrix<Precision>& a, const Matrix<Precision>& b) {

}
```

and then to make sure all the methods were generated for the desired types:

```
Matrix<float>;
Matrix<double>;
Matrix<long double>;
Matrix<int>;
```

g++ now gives an error on the specification of the type (which does nothing)
and the function is generated as inline, so it is not callable.

Is there any way to do this in C++20? Do modules solve this problem?

Comment: IMHO, If you want to keep the `.h`/`.hpp` file "clean", then put the implentation into a `.tpp` or `.ipp` file and then `#include` that file at the bottom of the header file.  This lets you keep the files separate, but still give you the "It Just Works" behavior of defining the template in the header file.

Comment: You want a closed set of specializations? With the implementation tucked away? There's a mechanism for that. It's explicit template instantiation. It isn't new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is orthogonal to whether or not the operator is `inline`, the definition (body) of the template must be available at the point of instantiation.

You've explicitly instantiated the `Matrix` class, but the issue is your `operator *` is a free operator, and so it is independent of `Matrix` and needs to be instantiated separately.

**.h file:**

```
// template declaration
template <typename Precision>
Matrix<Precision> operator*(Matrix<Precision> const& a, Matrix<Precision> const& b);

// explicit instantiation declaration
extern template Matrix<float> operator*(Matrix<float> const&, Matrix<float> const&);
extern template Matrix<double> operator*(Matrix<double> const&, Matrix<double> const&);
```

**.cpp file:**

```
// template definition
template <typename Precision>
Matrix<Precision> operator*(Matrix<Precision> const& a, Matrix<Precision> const& b) {
  // . . .
}

// explicit instantiation
template Matrix<float> operator*(Matrix<float> const&, Matrix<float> const&);
template Matrix<double> operator*(Matrix<double> const&, Matrix<double> const&);
```

The downside of all this is nothing here will ever be inlined (unless you use LTO), which can hurt run-time performance. For this reason explicit template instantiation is rarely used.

Modules do not solve this, but they can speedup regular build times by parsing the headers only once and storing intermediate representation in binary form.